# custom route vercel app return something went wrong

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

I get an 404 error when I route to /something in deployed vercel app, Currently a nodejs server running but routes returns `An unexpected error has occurred.`

```
server.get('/something', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     let result = async () => await method();
result().then((e) => {
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ raw: e }))
}).catch((E)=> {
  console.log(E)
  res.status(400).end(JSON.stringify({ ERROR: E }))
}
)
```

Comment: What is `e`? Where does it come from?

Comment: dont thing about it i removed still 404